# Using powershell as Admin in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, powershell, subprocess

So I have a project I'm working on, and one thing I need to do is to run in the background the "netstat -nb" command at the PowerShell as admin and recive the results to the python program. 
I've been searching the web for a solution but never found one efficient out there. I'd be glad for some help.

```
"netstat -nb"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute the netstat command you can do so from Python directly.But you need to be running Python script as a Admin:

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.call("netstat -nb")
```

If you need to access the powershell netstat values inside the Python script then you can set variable in powershell and pass it to Python script.
Following is the powershell command:

```
$con=netstat -nb
& python.exe "FullPath of Python script file"-p $con
```

Python script:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[5])

for conn in sys.argv:
   print(conn)
```

Here we are looping the parameters passed (netstat output) and displaying.So you are passing powershell command result to Python script and displaying it there.
Following columns would be displayed:

[image]

Comment: Im running the .py program through cmd

Answer (score 0):

You can use subprocess library. About subprocess module you can check [this](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html) documentation for more detail and features. It helps you to solve your problem. You can use subprocess.Popen or subprocess.call or to get output from another script you can use subprocess.check_output.

You can use it like this piece of code:

```
import subprocess
import sys
output = subprocess.Popen(['python','sample.py','Hello'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print(output)
```

Inside of the sample.py script is:

```
import sys
my_message = "This is desired output. " + sys.argv[1]
print(my_message)
```

In your case you can use Popen as:

```
subprocess.Popen(['netstat','-nb'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```